# Eliminando linhas duplas de um Data.Frame

Tags: r, data.frame

Tenho um `data.Frame` com o seguinte comportamento:

```
     values        ind
1  10.82000 2011-01-03
2  11.75000 2011-01-03
3  10.82000 2011-01-03
4  11.75000 2011-01-03
5  10.82000 2011-01-03
6  11.75000 2011-01-03
7  10.84048 2011-01-04
8  11.79000 2011-01-04
9  10.87095 2011-01-05
10 11.84000 2011-01-05
11 10.88928 2011-01-06
12 11.88000 2011-01-06
13 10.92000 2011-01-07
14 12.03000 2011-01-07
15 10.93984 2011-01-10
...
121 11.67614 2011-03-03
122 12.47000 2011-03-03
123 11.67481 2011-03-04
124 12.44000 2011-03-04
125 11.68514 2011-03-09
126 12.44000 2011-03-09
127 11.68514 2011-03-09
128 12.44000 2011-03-09
129 11.68514 2011-03-09
130 12.44000 2011-03-09
131 11.68514 2011-03-09
132 12.44000 2011-03-09
133 11.68514 2011-03-09
134 12.44000 2011-03-09
135 11.67746 2011-03-10
```

É o seguinte, tenho q apagar as linhas de 1 a 4, deixando as linhas 5 e 6. Preciso apagar as linhas 125 até 133 deixando as linhas 134 e 135.

Observe que seria interessante apagar na ordem. Assim que eu vejo que tem repetições duas a duas eu gostaria de ir apagando até deixar a ultima repetição.

Tem como criar algo? Como sou iniciante no R estou desde ontem tentando criar alguma coisa mas esta bem dificil.

Comment: O legal é ver seu código, assim dá pra ver sua lógica e responder melhor. Pode [edit] a pergunta para acrescentar detalhes.

Comment: Não é bem um codigo. É apenas o comando Matriz[-c(1:4,15:18, 29:32, 43:46, 55:58,),].

Comment: como você mencionou `estou tentando criar um codigo/função` na pergunta...

Comment: Ok. Vou editar.

Comment: Atenção ao real efeito da função duplicated. Ela conta o número de duplicatas e não o número de linhas repetidas. A negação de duplicated conta o numero de nao duplicatas e conta a 1a de uma série de linhas duplicadas. Vale a pena conferir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma outra maneira de fazer isso é utilizando a função `duplicated`.

Utilizando a base recriada pelo Carlos.

```
df<- read.table(text = "values        ind
1  10.82000 2011-01-03
2  11.75000 2011-01-03
3  10.82000 2011-01-03
4  11.75000 2011-01-03
5  10.82000 2011-01-03
6  11.75000 2011-01-03
7  10.84048 2011-01-04
8  11.79000 2011-01-04
9  10.87095 2011-01-05
10 11.84000 2011-01-05
11 10.88928 2011-01-06
12 11.88000 2011-01-06
13 10.92000 2011-01-07
14 12.03000 2011-01-07
15 10.93984 2011-01-10
121 11.67614 2011-03-03
122 12.47000 2011-03-03
123 11.67481 2011-03-04
124 12.44000 2011-03-04
125 11.68514 2011-03-09
126 12.44000 2011-03-09
127 11.68514 2011-03-09
128 12.44000 2011-03-09
129 11.68514 2011-03-09
130 12.44000 2011-03-09
131 11.68514 2011-03-09
132 12.44000 2011-03-09
133 11.68514 2011-03-09
134 12.44000 2011-03-09
135 11.67746 2011-03-10")
```

A função `duplicated` encontra as linhas com valor duplicado.

```
duplicados <- duplicated(df,fromLast = TRUE)
```

O argumento `fromLast=TRUE` faz com que os valores considerados duplicados sejam as primeiras aparições.

O Comando abaixo te mostra quais são as linhas que contém os valores duplicados

```
which(duplicados)
```

Para obter o data frame sem os valores duplicados basta fazer um subset com o comando abaixo.

```
df[!duplicados,]
```

Answer (score 7):

Você pode usar o comando `unique`, ele vai deixar apenas as observações únicas do seu `data.frame`. Por exemplo, recriando sua base de dados:

```
df<- read.table(text = "values        ind
1  10.82000 2011-01-03
2  11.75000 2011-01-03
3  10.82000 2011-01-03
4  11.75000 2011-01-03
5  10.82000 2011-01-03
6  11.75000 2011-01-03
7  10.84048 2011-01-04
8  11.79000 2011-01-04
9  10.87095 2011-01-05
10 11.84000 2011-01-05
11 10.88928 2011-01-06
12 11.88000 2011-01-06
13 10.92000 2011-01-07
14 12.03000 2011-01-07
15 10.93984 2011-01-10
121 11.67614 2011-03-03
122 12.47000 2011-03-03
123 11.67481 2011-03-04
124 12.44000 2011-03-04
125 11.68514 2011-03-09
126 12.44000 2011-03-09
127 11.68514 2011-03-09
128 12.44000 2011-03-09
129 11.68514 2011-03-09
130 12.44000 2011-03-09
131 11.68514 2011-03-09
132 12.44000 2011-03-09
133 11.68514 2011-03-09
134 12.44000 2011-03-09
135 11.67746 2011-03-10")
```

E aplicando o `unique`.

```
unique(df)
      values        ind
1   10.82000 2011-01-03
2   11.75000 2011-01-03
7   10.84048 2011-01-04
8   11.79000 2011-01-04
9   10.87095 2011-01-05
10  11.84000 2011-01-05
11  10.88928 2011-01-06
12  11.88000 2011-01-06
13  10.92000 2011-01-07
14  12.03000 2011-01-07
15  10.93984 2011-01-10
121 11.67614 2011-03-03
122 12.47000 2011-03-03
123 11.67481 2011-03-04
124 12.44000 2011-03-04
125 11.68514 2011-03-09
126 12.44000 2011-03-09
135 11.67746 2011-03-10
```

Note que neste caso ele deixou as primeiras observações. Caso você queira deixar as últimas, conforme você descreveu na sua pergunta, basta colocar `fromLast = TRUE`.

```
unique(df, fromLast = TRUE)
      values        ind
5   10.82000 2011-01-03
6   11.75000 2011-01-03
7   10.84048 2011-01-04
8   11.79000 2011-01-04
9   10.87095 2011-01-05
10  11.84000 2011-01-05
11  10.88928 2011-01-06
12  11.88000 2011-01-06
13  10.92000 2011-01-07
14  12.03000 2011-01-07
15  10.93984 2011-01-10
121 11.67614 2011-03-03
122 12.47000 2011-03-03
123 11.67481 2011-03-04
124 12.44000 2011-03-04
133 11.68514 2011-03-09
134 12.44000 2011-03-09
135 11.67746 2011-03-10
```

Comment: Carlos, mais uma vez, muito obrigado!!