# Eu gostaria de deixar o data.frame sem elementos repetidos usei esse código:

Tags: r, string, data.frame

```
f<- c("Juca", "Sam", "Ze", "Anta", "Buddy", "Irma")
f<- sample(f, 3, FALSE)
a<- c("Juca", "Silas", "Ze", "Ziraldo", "bar", "Ramister", "Luizinho")
a<- sample(a, 3, FALSE)

b <- c("Mario", "Eneas", "Rita", "bar", "laplace", "Ramister")
b <- sample(b, 3, FALSE)

c<- c("Tadeu", "Mario", "Eneas", "Rita", "bar", "Alvim", "Zeca")
c<- sample(c, 3, FALSE)
d<- c("Tadeu", "Mario", "He_man", "Rita", "bar", "laplace", "Luizinho")
d<- sample(d, 3, FALSE)
e<- c("João", "Sam", "José", "Tadeu", "bar", "laplace", "Luizinho")
e<- sample(e, 3, FALSE)
g<- c("Tadeu", "Mario", "Eneas", "Rita", "bar", "laplace", "Luizinho")
g <- sample(g, 3, FALSE)
h<- c("Tadeu", "Irma", "Bogos", "Espiao", "Julios", "Luizinho")
h<- sample(h, 3, FALSE)
library("magrittr")
data.frame(f) %>% 
  data.frame(a) %>% 
  data.frame(b) %>% 
  data.frame(c) %>% 
  data.frame (d) %>% 
  data.frame(e) %>% 
  data.frame(g) %>% 
  data.frame(h)

escala <- (data.frame(f) %>% 
              data.frame(a) %>% 
              data.frame(b) %>% 
              data.frame(c) %>% 
              data.frame (d) %>% 
              data.frame(e) %>% 
              data.frame(g) %>% 
              data.frame(h))   
escala

escala<- escala[!duplicated(escala), ]
escala
```

Comment: Detalhe mais seu problema, @Lincoln.

Comment: essa é a saída, eu gostaria de eliminar repetições nas linhas   ;                                            
         f      a        b       c           d     e          g        h
1 Buddy Silas  Rita Alvim      bar   bar    Rita   Espiao
2   Sam   bar   bar   bar Luizinho Tadeu laplace Luizinho
3  Juca  Juca Eneas  Zeca     Rita  José   Eneas    Tadeu
>

Comment: Edite a pergunta com estes detalhes (e mais outros que julgar necessário para obter uma boa resposta).

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Eliminando linhas duplas de um Data.Frame](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91898/eliminando-linhas-duplas-de-um-data-frame)

Answer (score 0):

Não é necessário repetir tantas vezes as chamadas a `sample`, uma vez basta. Quanto ao resultado final, não é claro qual o formato pretendido, este código cira um `data.frame` só com uma coluna e sem repetições.

```
f <- c("Juca", "Sam", "Ze", "Anta", "Buddy", "Irma")
a <- c("Juca", "Silas", "Ze", "Ziraldo", "bar", "Ramister", "Luizinho")
b <- c("Mario", "Eneas", "Rita", "bar", "laplace", "Ramister")
c <- c("Tadeu", "Mario", "Eneas", "Rita", "bar", "Alvim", "Zeca")
d <- c("Tadeu", "Mario", "He_man", "Rita", "bar", "laplace", "Luizinho")
e <- c("João", "Sam", "José", "Tadeu", "bar", "laplace", "Luizinho")
g <- c("Tadeu", "Mario", "Eneas", "Rita", "bar", "laplace", "Luizinho")
h <- c("Tadeu", "Irma", "Bogos", "Espiao", "Julios", "Luizinho")

vetores <- ls(pattern = '^[[:alpha:]]$')


set.seed(2020)
escala <- lapply(mget(vetores), sample, size = 3)
escala <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, escala)
names(escala) <- LETTERS[seq.int(ncol(escala))]
escala
#         A     B     C        D        E     F        G        H
#1  Ziraldo Mario Alvim    Mario      Sam Buddy  laplace Luizinho
#2 Luizinho   bar Tadeu Luizinho     José  Anta Luizinho   Espiao
#3     Juca Eneas   bar      bar Luizinho   Sam     Rita     Irma
```

Comment: Preciso de um DF com 3 linhas e 8 colunas onde nao se repitam nomes nas linhas, é uma escala de trabalho ( os nomes são de 8 conjuntos F, A, B .....H     se puder me ajudar...                                                                                               
      f       a          b         c         d     e        g               h
1 Anta Ziraldo Mario  Zeca   bar  João  laplace    Bogos
2 Juca     bar  Rita   bar  Rita Tadeu    Tadeu Luizinho
3  Sam   Silas   bar Tadeu Mario   bar Luizinho    Tadeu

Comment: @LincolnLinhares Feito, veja se é isto que pretende.